# Is PHP a must need for developing Iphone Web Apps?

Tags: jquery, iphone

I'm new to iphone development and php.
I had to develop a iphone web application - what I cant understand is: Is it possible to develop without PHP by using web services etc?

I have developing using JQtouch / jquery Mobile?

Comment: You need to read up on the difference between server side and client side languages. What you use on server side doesn't matter as far as the iPhone is concerned.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no.

Any current web development platform will work just fine

Answer (score 0):

You can always do ASP.NET MVC and return JSON object to iPhone. Now that we have jQuery Mobile, it should be rather easy to do. See one example @ http://yobriefcase.posterous.com/practical-jquery-mobile-with-aspnet-mvc

Comment: jQuery Mobile hardly made this possible.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of other server-side scripting languages you can build an application with.  ASP.NET(C#/ VB / etc), Java, perl, whatever.